# select from date and todate it show values

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I need  when select Borrow Date and Return Date It show between this date of  value  how can i do this please help me what is error on it..

```
    // String status1 = request.getParameter("status1");
 // String com=" 1 = 1";

     // get connection
     Connection con = lm.Database.getConnection();
     PreparedStatement ps=null;
     ResultSet rs=null;
     String bdate=request.getParameter("bdate");
     String rdate=request.getParameter("rdate");
     //Statement st = con.createStatement();
     //ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery("select * from issues where mid = ?");

      String query = "select * from issues  where bdate= '?' and rdate='?'";
      ps.setString(1, bdate);
      ps.setString(2,rdate);
            ps = con.prepareStatement(query);

            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            System.out.println("query=="+rs);

    // ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from issues where mid = " + mid);

    // System.out.println("query=="+query);
     //PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from issues where = ?");
     if (! rs.next())
     {
         //out.println("<h4>Sorry! Record Not Found!</h4>");
         out.println("<p/> <a href='javascript:history.back()'>Back</a>");
         return;
     }
```

When i run above page

I get error like this..

```
An exception occurred processing JSP page /LRapplication/pages/search_dues.jsp at line 86

83:      //ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery("select * from issues where mid = ?");
84:     
85:       String query = "select * from issues  where bdate= '?' and rdate='?'";
86:       ps.setString(1, bdate);
87:       ps.setString(2,rdate);
88:             ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
89:           


Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:519)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:428)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)

    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.LRapplication.pages.search_005fdues_jsp._jspService(search_005fdues_jsp.java:163)
```

Thanks for advance... Note: I'm writing Java code in a JSP file instead of a Java class, so sorry for that irrelevant HTML noise.

Answer (score 0):

```
PreparedStatement ps=null;
ps.setString(1, bdate);
ps.setString(2,rdate);
ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
```

You can't access **ps** before you assgin it - thats why you get an error, it's still null.

Move the `ps = con.prepareStatement(query);` line up.

More info on how to use the PreparedStatement:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: when i move above it show like Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No parameters defined during prepareCall()

Comment: String query = "select * from issues  where bdate= '?' and rdate='?'";
       ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
       ps.setString(1, bdate);
       ps.setString(2,rdate);

Comment: You didn't actually read the article I linked, did you? Hint: `con.setAutoCommit(false);`

Comment: sir it still have same error and i change like this     String query = "select * from issues  where bdate= '?' and rdate='?'";
      try{
    con.setAutoCommit(false);
            ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
            ps.setString(1, bdate);
            ps.setString(2,rdate);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            con.commit();
      }
      catch (SQLException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }

Comment: i get error like this  <th>Borrow Date</th>
 <th>Renewal Date</th>
 </tr>
 <tr><td><%=rs.getString("mid") %></td><td><a href=book_view.jsp?isbn=<%=rs.getString("isbn")  %>><%=rs.getString("isbn") %></a></td><td><%=rs.getString("bdate") %></td><td><%=rs.getString("rdate") %></td></tr>
 <%while (rs.next())
 {
  %> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException